# How is Hogwarts able to hold feasts all the time?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, food

How is Hogwarts able to hold feasts with a seemingly endless amount of food all the time? How is all the food grown and transported to Hogwarts, and who oversees it all?

Comment: Call me crazy, but I am gonna guess something to do with magic. :)

Comment: @Lexible magic has it's limitations, and hundreds of growing kids still need to be fed

Comment: "magic has it's limitations" [citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_needed)